# Backtracking to find the maze exit. Why does my function always return True?

Tags: python, scope, global, recursive-backtracking

My code successfully makes its way through all the possible paths in the maze... but it **always returns `True`**, even though true only updates if certain conditions are met (having reached the edge of the maze). **It seems I have misunderstanding of scope. This is my first time using the global keyword.**

Here's some sample input/output. Above is the maze, the two numbers are (x, y) coordinates of current position in the maze. **'k' is the starting position, '#' is a wall**.

```
# # ## #
# #k#  #
# # # ##
# # #  #
#     ##
########
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 5
5 5
5 4
6 4
5 3
5 2
6 2
6 1
2 5
1 5
1 4
1 3
1 2
1 1
3 1
True
```

```
found = False
def find_start(maze):
    start = None
    for i in range(len(maze)):
        print(maze[i])
        for j in range(len(maze[i])):
            if maze[i][j] == 'k':
                if start == None:
                    start = (i, j)
                else:
                    raise "There should be no multiple Kates"
    if not start:
        raise "There should be one Kate"
    return start

def has_exit(maze):
    visited = [[False for _ in range(len(maze[i]))] for i in range(len(maze))]
    y, x = find_start(maze)
    def backtrack(maze, x, y):
        visited[y][x] = True
        print(x, y)
        if x == 0 or x == (len(maze[y]) - 1) or y == 0 or y == (len(maze) - 1) or x > len(maze[y+1]) - 1 or x > len(maze[y-1]) - 1: # This last condition is the hard one.
            print('Found edge')
            global found
            found = True
            return
        if maze[y][x+1] == ' ' and not visited[y][x+1]:
            backtrack(maze, x+1, y)
        if maze[y][x-1] == ' ' and not visited[y][x-1]:
            backtrack(maze, x-1, y)
        if maze[y+1][x] == ' ' and not visited[y+1][x]:
            backtrack(maze, x, y+1)
        if maze[y-1][x] == ' ' and not visited[y-1][x]:
            backtrack(maze, x, y-1)
        
    backtrack(maze, x, y)
    if found:
        print(found)
        return True
    else:
        print(found)
        return False
```

Comment: What source are you using to learn Python? `raise "..."` was deprecated *ages* ago, and is not legal in Python 3, or even Python 2.7.

Comment: Also, don't use a global variable. Have `backtrack` *return*  a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place `found` is assigned a value is the first time through the code `=False` Then whenever the code hits `backtrack` it assigns it `True`.  Importantly for your question, you never reset `found`, so as soon as set to `True` one time, it will never reset.  Since you are recursing over all possible paths, you will hit an edge eventually, so `found=True` eventually for any run.

I agree with the other suggestions about using return values from functions, but here you just need to reset your state appropriately for the recursive search.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided start point for you code to debug further.

However the basic rules for global keyword in Python are:

- When we create a variable inside a function, it is local by default.
- When we define a variable outside of a function, it is global by
  default.You don't have to use global keyword.
- We use global keyword
  to read and write a global variable inside a function.
- Use of global
  keyword outside a function has no effect.

[Source](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) - More examples are found in this source